# AFNetworking make the same download for different files

Tags: ios, afnetworking

I use AFNetworking for getting my files from the server.

I need to make one operation vary often. So here is a code below about what I am saying:

```
- (void)downloadFileWithPath:(NSString *)urlPath withFileName:(NSString *)fileName
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlPath];

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *path = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

    operation.outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:path append:NO];

    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

        // DO SOMETHING HERE

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);

    }];

    [operation start];
}
```

So, what I need. At first I need to download xml file and save it to Documents directory (I did it. I don't need explain how to make this).
Here I invoke this code:

`[object downloadFileWithPath:urlPath withFileName:fileName]`

After xml file was loaded I need to invoke next download using the same method, but in this case for another file .zip for example. It means I need to figure out when xml file is loaded (in this case in setCompletionBlockWithSuccess) and run download .zip file.

I added comment // DO SOMETHING HERE in the code above. I suppose I need to perform some selector here for different request for xml file for zip file, because each time I need to make different operation. So it looks like we load xml file parser it after that we get url for zip file and again make download but in this case for zip file using the same method.

So of course I can create two different methods for example

```
- (void)downloadXMLFileWithPath:(NSString *)urlPath withFileName:(NSString *)fileName;  

- (void)downloadZIPFileWithPath:(NSString *)urlPath withFileName:(NSString *)fileName;
```

with the same content and different in setCompletionBlockWithSuccess, but I think it is bad decision because of duplicated code.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlPath];

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *path = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

    operation.outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:path append:NO];

    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

        // BUT DIFFERENT HERE

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);

    }];

    [operation start];
```

So, what do you think which of variants better make duplicated code or pass selector into the method for downloading files.

Also here is an issue with selector if we perform it we got this warning:

```
PerformSelector may cause a leak because its selector is unknown
```

Comment: How about simply creating one version of that method which accepts a completion handling block as a parameter, wouldnt that do?

Comment: I don't think that I've understood you right. Can you explain your point of view?

Comment: I ve made system where - downloadFileWithPath method get block as argument. Before I invoke this method I create block that have code for getting another file (.zip). I pass this block to downloadFileWithPath and wait until AFNetworking block will be finished with success. After block(); and it is work right now. am I right. How about clear code is this good solution or not? I will share my code.

Comment: You are describing pretty much exactly what I had suggested ;)..

Comment: Yes, of course thank you a lot. Just clarify if I understood you correct.

Comment: I have added answer can you comment my code please. It is very important for me. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks this man [Till](https://stackoverflow.com/users/91282/till)

I have made this class below that solves my problem:

```
#import "NetworkManager.h"
#import "AFHTTPRequestOperation.h"

typedef void (^NetworkManagerBlock)(void);

@implementation NetworkManager

- (NSString *)fileNameFromUrlString:(NSString *)urlString
{
    NSArray *components = [urlString componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];
    return [components lastObject];
}

- (void)downloadFileWithUrlString:(NSString *)urlString withCompletionBlock:(NetworkManagerBlock)block
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *fileName = [self fileNameFromUrlString:urlString];
    NSString *path = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

    operation.outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:path append:NO];

    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

        block();

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);

    }];

    [operation start];
}

- (void)downloadUpadatesPlistWithUrlString:(NSString *)urlString
{
    NetworkManagerBlock block = ^ {
        [self fetchZipFilesFromUpdatesPlistFile];
    };

    [self downloadFileWithUrlString:urlString withCompletionBlock:block];
}

- (void)fetchZipFilesFromUpdatesPlistFile
{
    NSString* documentsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString* filePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"updates.plist"];

    NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

    for (NSDictionary *item in [dict objectForKey:@"updates"]) {
        [self downloadZipFileWithUrlString:[item objectForKey:@"url"]];
    }
}

- (void)downloadZipFileWithUrlString:(NSString *)urlString
{
    NetworkManagerBlock block = ^ {
        NSLog(@"ZIP file loaded");
    };

    [self downloadFileWithUrlString:urlString withCompletionBlock:block];
}

@end
```

What's about clean code or readability? What do you think? Maybe you have advice or comments.

Comment: One more problem here is in order download files. For example if I download file 1.zip and 2.zip they will be downloaded in the reverse order. at first 2.zip and than 1.zip